# Input checked changes button class

Tags: javascript, css, checkbox, input, radio-button

Looking to remove disable class from button and add enable class when the radio button is checked as well as 1 or more checkbox is checked.

```
<div>
    <input name="select-customer" type="radio">btn 1
    <input name="select-customer" type="radio">btn 2
</div>
<div>    
    <input type="checkbox" name="choice-selection">Choice 1
    <input type="checkbox" name="choice-selection">Choice 2
    <input type="checkbox" name="choice-selection">Choice 3
    <input type="checkbox" name="choice-selection">Choice 4
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dLyvo7d0/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        $('input:radio').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
                if (($this).prop('checked')) {
                     $this.closest('span').addClass('enable');
                     $this.closest('span').removeClass('disable');
                }else{
                     $this.closest('span').addClass('disable');
                     $this.closest('span').removeClass('enable');
                }
        });
        $('input:checkbox').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
                if (($this).prop('checked')) {
                     $this.closest('span').addClass('enable');
                     $this.closest('span').removeClass('disable');
                }else{
                     $this.closest('span').addClass('disable');
                     $this.closest('span').removeClass('enable');
                }
        });
    });

});
```

```css
.disable {
    background: gray;
}

.enable {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div>
        <span><input name="select-customer" type="radio"/>btn 1</span>
        <span><input name="select-customer" type="radio"/>btn 2</span>
    </div>
    <div>    
         <span><input type="checkbox" name="choice-selection"/>Choice 1</span>
         <span><input type="checkbox" name="choice-selection"/>Choice 2</span>
         <span><input type="checkbox" name="choice-selection"/>Choice 3</span>
         <span><input type="checkbox" name="choice-selection"/>Choice 4</span>
    </div>
            <button class="disable" id="button">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure JavaScript function, which listens for a click event, then changes the button's class based on the inputs' clicked state:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if(document.querySelector('[name="select-customer"]:checked') ||
     document.querySelector('[name="choice-selection"]:checked')
    ) {
    document.querySelector('button').className= 'enable';
  }
  else {
    document.querySelector('button').className= 'disable';
  }
});
```

```css
.disable {
  background: gray;
}

.enable {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input name="select-customer" type="radio">btn 1
  <input name="select-customer" type="radio">btn 2
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice-selection">Choice 1
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice-selection">Choice 2
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice-selection">Choice 3
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice-selection">Choice 4
</div>
<button class="disable">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $( "input[name='select-customer']" ).is(':checked')) {
      if( $( "input[name='choice-selection']" ).is(':checked')){
               $('#btn').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
                } else {
                     $('#btn').prop('disabled', false);     
                    }
            }
}
```

Try this